# Unable to make RBAC work on Minikube: Make sure that your network manifest supports RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run Minikube with RBAC but unable to create a cluster:

Using this:

```
minikube start --memory=8192 --cpus=4 --vm-driver=virtualbox --extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC
```

Error:

```
E0113 13:02:54.464971   65250 start.go:343] Error starting cluster:  kubeadm init error 
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 
 running command: : Process exited with status 1
================================================================================
An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?
To opt out of these messages, run the command:
    minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]: %
```

Comment: what is your minikube version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: **--extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC**

Should be: **--extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=RBAC**

Example:

```
minikube start \
  --kubernetes-version v1.13.7 \
  --vm-driver=kvm2 \
  --memory=4096 \
  --cpus=2 \
  --disk-size=60G \
  --extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=RBAC
```

Comment: I can confirm that it works well with minikube version v1.30.1 on MacOS